# How to run CoMIRVA jar?

Tags: java, jar

I am new in java but I need to run CoMIRVA
(http://www.cp.jku.at/people/schedl/Research/Development/CoMIRVA/webpage/CoMIRVA.html)

I've download comirva-0.2.N3.jar and put the required libraries in the same folder.
When I run the command "java -jar comirva-0.2.N3.jar" it gave me:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cp/util/ThreadListener"

They say in the site that we "need the required libraries in your classpath to run the jar file".

How do we put the required libraries in the classpath to run the jar file?
I allready tried to "SET CLASSPATH="C:......jar" but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The grid on that site allows you to download the OS-appropriate run script:

- run_comirva.bat for Microsoft
- run_comirva.sh for Linux/Unix

Inspecting the .bat, there are a host of other dependencies that need to be included in the classpath.  I would suggest that you use the script as provided.

EDIT:

the bat is looking for these files in these directories:

```
.;
./CoMIRVA;
./CoMIRVA/classes;
./CoMIRVA/classes/comirva;
./CoMIRVA/lib/commons-logging-api.jar;
./CoMIRVA/lib/cp.jar;
./CoMIRVA/lib/jama-1.0.2.jar;
./CoMIRVA/lib/jl1.0.jar;
./CoMIRVA/lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar;
./CoMIRVA/lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar;
./CoMIRVA/lib/mp3spi1.9.4.jar;
./CoMIRVA/lib/stax-api-1.0.jar;
./CoMIRVA/lib/tritonus_remaining.jar;
./CoMIRVA/lib/tritonus_share.jar;
./CoMIRVA/lib/wstx-lgpl-2.0.3.jar;
./CoMIRVA/lib/secondstring.jar
```

With that in mind, it appears that having your comirva-0.2.N3.jar in your working directory is fine, but you need to move your dependencies to a directory called `CoMIRVA/lib/` (using the appropriate slashed for your environment) below your working directory.

Comment: I had to extract the jar file content to that folder and after that it worked pretty well.
Tks m8!